# How to Start fullTrustProcess exe on UWP update installation?

Tags: uwp

How should packagemanifest look like in order to run background (out of process) systemEvent initialized on ServicingComplete (**on update installed of UWP**)
that runs fulltrustprocess exe?

In general i want to start the exe when UWP application is updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-19041)?
In the example XML code you'll see this piece of code:

```xml
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
</Capabilities>
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This is valid answer but only a part of the solution.

Comment: Did you also take a look at the link I provided?

Comment: Since the answer covers the  scope of the question i will accept it as correct, anyway - The complete solution requires you to register the task that you need on application startup so you will be able to enable this feature.